# Circuit Design and Simulation

Tags: software, electronics

I want to design some circuits of my own. My area of expertise is in Computer Science Engineering. I have listed out the components which are essential in the circuit. I want a software which can be used to design and simulate circuits for real time projects. Please suggest me the best among them. Thank you.

@AkhilRajagopal

Comment: I have voted to close this question and am recommending that you re-ask it at the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) (but I would also recommend [SPICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE) or [P-SPICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OrCAD#OrCAD_EE_PSpice))

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* AKHIL RAJAGOPAL, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use LTspice, which uses the same physical models as the alternatives listed by Chuck. LTSpice models can be directly imported to Eagle, which is somehow state of the art programm to PCB-design.

Comment: +1 for "somehow state of the art" lol

Comment: There are lot of different tools for PCB design. I usually use Eagle, but I know Altium is another widely used tool. It is like a religion and we can argue for hours which is the best one.

Comment: No, I understand. I use Eagle as well.